# How to customize build-in widgets in Android (menu, notification, spinners etc.)?

Tags: android, layout, widget

Hi I want to customize colour palette in Android widgets.

Orange colour is good but it can be done better.

Things which I want to do:
- override colours in menu after press and focus
- override colours in ongoing notification bar
- override colour in EditText frame
and finally 
- override spinner focus and press colour

I want to use build-in method forcing Android do build menu and passing it for me.

As a last resort I may build it from scratch, but this is less welcome, from obvious reasons :-).

thanks in advance,
Patrick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think You're looking for [themes](http://d.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html). You can set menu colors etc. throughout Your entire application.

Comment: If I can ask you for revision. I still have a problem with this section. I followed guidelines, so I declared style with following parameter:
<item name="android:drawable/menuitem_background_pressed">@drawable/menuitem_background_pressed_appName</item>
<item name="android:drawable/menuitem_background_focus">@drawable/menuitem_background_focus_appName</item>

The objects under appName follows the same pattern like in android resource files.

Comment: There not too much space.
In console I recieve following info:
[2009-11-12 11:26:20 - appName]W/ResourceType( 8022): Skipping entry 0x10801b7 in package table 0 because it is not complex!
[2009-11-12 11:26:20 - appName]WARNING: Type not found for resource #010801b7

I have no clue what to do next :-/.